# Read csv with sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

I'm having some trouble to read big csv files with my R, so i'm trying to use the package sqldf to read just some column or lines from the csv.

I tried this:

```
test <- read.csv.sql("D:\\X17065382\\Documents\\cad\\2016_mar\\2016_domicilio_mar.csv", sql = "select * from file  limit 5", header = TRUE, sep = ",", eol = "\n")
```

but i got this problem:

> Error in connection_import_file(conn@ptr, name, value, sep, eol, skip) : RS_sqlite_import: D:\X17065382\Documents\cad\2016_mar\2016_domicilio_mar.csv line 198361 expected 1 columns of data but found 2

Comment: The error message really says it all.  Line 198361 has 2 fields of data whereas all prior lines have one field.

Comment: Also note that you can use the `filter=` argument in `read.csv.sql`

Answer (score 2):

If you're not too fussy about which package you use, `data.table` has a great function for doing just what you need

```
library(data.table)

file <- "D:\\X17065382\\Documents\\cad\\2016_mar\\2016_domicilio_mar.csv"

fread(file, nrows = 5)
```

Comment: Got this problem: Error in fread(file = nomes_cad_2016, nrows = 5) : 
  Opened 0TB (3452861433 bytes) file ok but could not memory map it. This is a 32bit process. Please upgrade to 64bit.

Comment: And it woudn't solve my problem, cause what I nedd is to read all rows (7 milion) and some of the 150 columns. I couldn't read the whole file because of memory space, so i'm trying to read just some part of it.

Comment: you can also use the `col.names` argument in `fread` to specify which columns to read in. If you're struggling with memory then sqldf isn't going to help: you would be better off loading the data into a database

Comment: Oh, this is a good idea, It does solve my problem. I tried with some data and worked, but when I tried with the data that I need I got an error: > Error in fread("D:\\X17065382\\Documents\\cad\\2016_mar\\2016_domicilio_mar.csv",  : 
  Opened 0TB (1045835468 bytes) file ok but could not memory map it. This is a 32bit process. Please upgrade to 64bit.

Comment: Try swapping to the 64 bit version of R in global options

Answer (score 0):

Like **Shinobi_Atobe** said, the `fread()` function from data.table is working really well. If you prefer to use base R you could also use : `read.csv()` or `read.csv2()`.

i.e.:

```
read.csv2(file_path, nrows = 5)
```

Also what do you mean by "big files" ? 1GB, 10GB, 100GB?

Comment: Tried and I got this error: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 0 Kb Error during wrapup: could not allocate memory (0 Mb) in C function 'R_AllocStringBuffer'

Comment: And it woudn't solve my problem, cause what I nedd is to read all rows (7 milion) and some of the 150 columns. I couldn't read the whole file because of memory space, so i'm trying to read just some part of it.

Comment: You get this error while doing : read.csv2("D:\\X17065382\\Documents\\cad\\2016_mar\\2016_domicilio_mar.csv", nrows = 5) ? I am using this function to load over 5GB .CSV without any problem. What is the size of your data?

Comment: Well you said you want to only read some rows, that's why I tought read.csv() would have work for you. But without the data sample it's kinda hard to find out what the problem is, because even with read.csv.sql() I get it to work.

Comment: Oh, i worngly put  (header = TRUE, sep = ","), my bad. It worked. With this i think i'm going to read the column names and put the file in postgres to read all the rows from some of the colunms. Its going to be a longer way than reading the columns that I wanted with the sqldf package but it will work. Thanks

Comment: @AlexandreMáriodeFreitas Good, at least it can maybe help you. I'm still wondering why the read.csv.sql() function isn't working for you, I got no problem on a big data frame when trying your code.  Do you have any sample of your data ?

Comment: Don't have =(. the read.csv.sql also worked with other csv files, but with some csv it's not working. it also give this error: Error in connection_import_file(conn@ptr, name, value, sep, eol, skip) : 
  RS_sqlite_getline could not realloc

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
require(sqldf)
df <- read.csv.sql("C:\\your_path\\CSV1.csv", "select * from file where Name='Asher'")
df
```